# kubernetes dashboard - how to view list of defined namespaces without the need to search a certain namespace manually

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard

When i do a RoleBinding to a certain user, 
i wish this user could be able to access the k8s dashboard and already see the allowed namespaces i defined in the yaml.
the issue is that, after a user access the dashboard, he needs to type manually the required namespace, pressing 'Enter', only then he sees its features!

If for example i define namespaces A,B and C to user John, can you provide a yaml template that allows John to access and immediately see and select between namespaces A,b and C? 
(currently, under the 'namespaces' field,  he needs to type 'A' end 'Enter' in order to view)

Comment: As far as I understand your question, you would have to pull [dashboard image](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/kubernetes-dashboard/values.yaml#L6-L7), change search box for dropdown with namespaces, and use your own image instead of the default one.

Comment: i think i found an answer through yaml file:  adding clusterRoleBinding with permissions for "namespaces", then, for each namespace in request, adding roleBinding with that particular namespace

Comment: Hey @Eyal Jacob, happy to hear that! If you found an answer could you please add it and mark it as accepted for future visbility?